# Setting multiple labels to transparent across 1.000 forms?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-7, delphi-xe

I skinned my software with Devexpress and I found that the labels were non-transparent causing them to have grey background.

There's just endless forms, so I was wondering whether there was a way to do this task (of setting labels to transparent) automatically.

I did a similar thing earlier, the Devexpress controls on the form had LookAndFeel.NativeStyle = True, I used Grep Search to replace it to False on all dfm forms. In the label's case however, the transparent property is not present.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you committed to doing this in the IDE, or would you be okay with it being done at run-time?

Comment: Robert, that would be fantastic - at run time I mean. What can I do to achieve that result?

Comment: Rather than doing it at design time you could perhaps more easily do this at runtime

Comment: Iterate across all the controls in the form and whenever you find a label change the properties as desired

Comment: I've used GExperts for a massive search and replace. Can you use it to locate all occurences of TLabel in the dfm's and replace by TLabel<CR>Transparent=True - I dont know how to declare the <CR> bit though.

Comment: In Delphi XE the default value for TLabel.Transparent is true. So if it doesn't appear in the DFM, it should already be OK. You have tagged three Delphi versions - which one has the problem?

Comment: Delphi 7, I use XE as well, since there are multiple projects but for this one only 7 will do.

Comment: +1 for a question inspiring several clever solutions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The global `Screen` variable keeps track of all forms:

```
procedure MakeLabelsTransparent(AParent: TWinControl);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  with AParent do
    for I := 0 to ControlCount - 1 do
      if Controls[I] is TLabel then
        TLabel(Controls[I]).Transparent := True
      else if Controls[I] is TWinControl then
        MakeLabelsTransparent(TWinControl(Controls[I]));
end;

procedure TMainForm.ActiveFormChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with Screen do
    if (ActiveCustomForm <> nil) and (ActiveCustomForm.Tag = 0) then
    begin
      MakeLabelsTransparent(ActiveCustomForm);
      ActiveCustomForm.Tag := 1;
    end;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.OnActiveFormChange := ActiveFormChange;
end;
```

And if you have to use the Tag property for a particular form, then omit this check: it wouldn't really get that much slower.

Comment: +1 Ingenious, NGLN. I wasn't aware of how to use OnActiveFormChange.

Comment: Perfect, work on all MDI forms simultaneously, simply perfect... Thank you.

Comment: Labels need not be owned by the form in which they live. It would be more robust to recursively walk the Controls indexed property.

Answer (score 9):

For this type of task, GExperts contains the **Set Component Properties** tool:

> This tool waits in the background
>   until you compile a project.  It then
>   scans the current project's forms to
>   check for components with certain
>   properties and changes those
>   properties to a defined value.  This
>   tool is useful to deactivate datasets
>   or database connections before you
>   compile your applications, but it can
>   be used for any similar situations as
>   well.  To activate the scanning,
>   enable the checkbox next to this
>   expert in the GExperts Configuration
>   screen.

It can be used to set a property which is not yet in the DFM as well, and only requires one additional entry in the GExpert configuration, and a recompile.

I have just tested it and it works as expected.

Comment: I recommend this as it can be possible that some day you want a non-transparent label, and you could set it differently.

Comment: Definitely second best solution. I had no idea of this. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 5):

At design time, you can just parse all .dfm then add the

```
  Transparent = True
```

line just after any

```
  object MyLabel : TLabel
```

line.

At runtime, you may override the `TCustomForm.DoCreate` and `TCustomFrame.Create` methods, as such:

```
type
  THookedForm = class(TCustomForm)
    procedure HookedDoCreate;
  end;

  THookedFrame = class(TCustomFrame)
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

var
  PatchForm, OriginalForm: TPatchEvent;
  PatchPositionForm: PPatchEvent = nil;
  PatchFrame, OriginalFrame: TPatchEvent;
  PatchPositionFrame: PPatchEvent = nil;

procedure PatchCreate;
var ov: cardinal;
begin
  // hook TForm:
  PatchPositionForm := PPatchEvent(@THookedForm.DoCreate);
  OriginalForm := PatchPositionForm^;
  PatchForm.Jump := $E9; // Jmp opcode
  PatchForm.Offset := PtrInt(@THookedForm.HookedDoCreate)-PtrInt(PatchPositionForm)-5;
  if not VirtualProtect(PatchPositionForm, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, @ov) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  PatchPositionForm^ := PatchForm; // enable Hook
  // hook TFrame:
  PatchPositionFrame := PPatchEvent(@TCustomFrame.Create);
  OriginalFrame := PatchPositionFrame^;
  PatchFrame.Jump := $E9; // Jmp opcode
  PatchFrame.Offset := PtrInt(@THookedFrame.Create)-PtrInt(PatchPositionFrame)-5;
  if not VirtualProtect(PatchPositionFrame, 5, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, @ov) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  PatchPositionFrame^ := PatchFrame; // enable Hook
end;

{ THookedForm }

procedure THookedForm.HookedDoCreate;
var i: integer;
begin
  // enumerate all labels, then set Transparent := true
  for i := 0 to Components.Count-1 do
    if Components[i] is TLabel then
      TLabel(Components[i]).Transparent := true;
  DoCreate; // call initial code
end;

{ THookedFrame }

constructor THookedFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var i: integer;
begin
  // enumerate all labels, then set Transparent := true
  for i := 0 to Components.Count-1 do
    if Components[i] is TLabel then
      TLabel(Components[i]).Transparent := true;
  inherited Create(AOwner); // call normal constructor
end;

....

initialization
  PatchCreate;
```

Comment: @Warren It's my first solution. And the OP asked for a run-time solution, so I gave one generic solution of this request.

Comment: This is a good solution! :-)  Reading my comment I see I'm making NO sense.

Answer (score 5):

A related tip (I always forget to make use of this handy feature):

1. Configure the label the way you want to have it;
2. Select it on the form;
3. Go to `Component/Create component template`;
4. You can then a name for the template:

[image]

From then on, the template appears as a new component type in your tool palette, with the settings that you prefer.

<sub>(Yeah, I know this doesn't change current labels)</sub>

Comment: nice, will try this out on one of my custom components whose defaults are set in stone

Comment: Although this doesn't provide a solution to the question it's **really useful**. I never once thought about clicking the menu 'Create component template'. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `BackColor` property to `Color.Transparent`.

Comment: Well, I think OP wants to set `Label.Transparent := True` but the real issue here is how to automate the change

Answer (score 1):

The following should work: the transparent-property is present in the DFM-file only if the value is not the default. So you can us a Grep-Search to insert the "Transparent=TRUE" just in the next line after the "=TLabel". I have not tried this myself, but it is easy to try...